# if else function returns not what I asked for

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have the following function

```
aa<-function(x){
    if (x==c(3,4,5))
        return (1)
    if (x==c(6,7,8))
        return(2)
    else
        return(0)
}
```

I then try the following:

```
> `aa(3)`
[1] 1
> `aa(4`)
[1] 0
> `aa(5)`
[1] 0
> `aa(6)`
[1] 2
> `aa(7)`
[1] 0
> `aa(8)`
[1] 0
```

I don't know why only `aa(3)` and `aa(6)` gives me the desired outcome, while `aa(4)` and `aa(5)` won't return 1 and `aa(7)` and `aa(8)` won't return 2. How can I correct my code so that a value of either 3, 4, or 5 returns 1, and 6, 7, or 8 returns 2, and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Did you want to use the [`%in%` operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) instead of `==`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? ... you ask. You should have seen a warning message ( two of them in fact) that you didn't tell us about.

```
> aa(4)
[1] 0
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == c(3, 4, 5)) return(1) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == c(6, 7, 8)) return(2) else return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The `if` statement was handling the results of the `x == c(3, 4, 5)` and `x == c(6, 7, 8)` operations, each of which returned a 3-element logical vector. The `if()`-function only wants a single value and issues a warning if it gets more, telling you that only the first item was used.

There are several ways to handle this. The `%in%` infix function is one and you could also use either `match()` or `any()` to deliver a single result back to the `if()` function:

```
 aa<-function(x){
    if (match(x, c(3,4,5)) )   # match returns a location; any value > 0 will be TRUE
        return (1)
    if (match(x, c(6,7,8)) )
        return(2)
    else
        return(0)
}
```

Or:

```
aa<-function(x){
    if ( any( x==c(3,4,5)) ) # a single logical TRUE if any of the "=="-tests are TRUE.
        return (1)
    if ( any( x==c(6,7,8)) )
        return(2)
    else
        return(0)
}
aa(4)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For membership tests, use `%in%`, not `==`. Look at the difference in the R console:

```
> 3 == c(3,4,5)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 3 %in% c(3,4,5)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
aa<-function(x){
  if (x==3|x==4|x==5){
    return (1)}
  else if (x==6|x==7|x==8){
    return(2)}
  else{
    return(0)}
}
```

Then I have

```
aa(4)
[1] 1
```

Note that `|` is the "or" operator